# Demonstrate that this equation has three real roots if fulfills this condition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have this: demonstrate that this equation

$$ {x}^{3}+p\,x+q=0 $$

has one real root if "p" is positive and has three real roots if

$$ \frac{{q}^{2}}{4}+\frac{{p}^{3}}{27}<0 $$

I did demonstrate that it has one real root, but the three real roots I don't know how to manage to demonstrate them and I don't have idea how to approach it.

I'm in first year calculus.

Comment: This is a STEP question used for UK university maths admissions. The Student Room has good unofficial solutions to these questions.

Comment: i am from spain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler is to use symmetric functions of the roots $x_0,x_1$ of the derivative: by the intermediate value theorem, $f(x)$ has $3$ real roots if and only if $f(x_0)f(x_1)<0$.

It's easy to compute $f(x_0)f(x_1)$ as a symmetric function of $x_0$ and $x_1$:
$$f(x_0)f(x_1)=(x_0x_1)^3+px_0x_1(x_0^2+x_1^2)+q(x_0^3+x_1^3)+p^2x_0x_1+pq(x_0+x_1)+q^2.$$
Now, $x_0$ and $x_1$ are the two (opposite) roots of $-\dfrac p3$, so that
$$x_0x_1=\frac p 3, \quad x_0+x_1=0,\quad x_0^2+x_1^2=-\frac{2p}3. $$
Replacing in $f(x_0)f(x_1)$, you'll find the condition:
$$\frac{p^3}{27} -\frac{2p^3}9+\frac{p^3}3+q^2=\frac{4p^3}{27}+q^2<0,$$
which you can rewrite as$$\Bigl(\frac p3\Bigr)^3+\Bigl(\frac q2\Bigr)^2<0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using concepts from analysis. Let $f(x)=x^3+p\,x+q$ and $p<0$. If the equation has three roots, then $f$ has a local maximum and a local minimum, and the local minimum has to be negative. The derivative of $f$ has two roots:$\pm\sqrt{-p/3\,}$. The negative one corresponds to the maximum and the positive one to the minimum. The condition for the existence of three roots is then $f(\sqrt{-p/3\,})<0$.

**Edit**: you also want the local maximum to be positive, that is, $f(-\sqrt{-p/3\,})>0$. Thanks go to Arthur for pointing this out.

Comment: Don't forget that you also want $f(-\sqrt{-p/3\,})>0$

Comment: @Arthur You are right, I forgot that condition.

Comment: thank you, but i need the second part because the first part i had done it.

Comment: But this answers the second part, the condition for the existence of three real roots.

Answer (score 1):

This comes quite directly, using Cardano's famous method for cubics. Starting with your equation, let $$\begin{align}u+v &= x \\ 3uv + p &= 0\end{align}$$

Now, substituting in the original cubic (and simplifying): $$ u^3 + v^3 +(3uv + p)(u+v) + q = 0$$

We see that $$\begin{align}u^3 + v^3 &= -q \\ u^3v^3 &= \frac{-p^3}{27} \end{align}$$
From this we know that $U = u^3,\, V = v^3$ satisfy the degree two equation $$X^2+qX-\frac{p^3}{27} = 0$$

Studying the discriminant of this equation and undoing the change of variables will get you the result you wish.

Comment: buuufff, its very difficult

Comment: has any other methode? because I didn't understand this methode

Comment: It's not that difficult, but it works well only if there is one real root (that's precisely why roots of negative numbers were introduced).

Comment: @Bernard I don't understand what you mean. Assuming $p,q$ are real, this works for explaining both cases (not distinguishing the case of multiple roots) of the original polynomial: One real root and two complex roots, or three real roots.

Comment: @GPerez: That's fairly simple: the case when there are 3 real roots is the case when the discriminant is $<0$, hence $u^3, v^3$ are *complex* numbers, and you'll have to compute cubic roots of complex numbers, which requires some trigonometry. Btw, there's a small error in your final equation: it should be $+\dfrac{-p^3}{27}$.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the correction. I'm aware there are complex number calculations involved, but what's wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing, except it's not simple (you can't obtain formulae involving only roots in the *real* sense. And it's not enough to prove there are three real roots.

Answer (score 1):

Let's $\alpha$ is any real root of $f(x)=x^3+px+q$,then 
$$
f(x)=(x-\alpha)(x^2+ax+b).
$$
From this we get $\alpha=a$, so $$
f(x)=(x-a)(x^2+ax+b),
$$
and 
$$
b-a^2=p,-ab=q.
$$
Now we put these equations in 
$$
\frac{{q}^{2}}{4}+\frac{{p}^{3}}{27}<0
$$
and get 
$$
4a^6-12ba^4-15a^2b^2-4b^3=(b+2a^2)^2(a^2-4b)\gt0,
$$
so $a^2-4b\gt0$ and our polynomial has three real roots.